# Do I need to use <> empty angle brackets for generics?

Tags: java, generics

I've seen the following code, used for pagination of SQL results:

```
Page<EmployeeEvent> employeeEventPage = new PageImpl<>(employeeEvents, null, 10);
```

Why do we need to use the "<>" in this context, giving we're talking Java 8?
Is that not the same as

```
Page<EmployeeEvent> employeeEventPage = new PageImpl(employeeEvents, null, 10);
```

?

Page is defined as follows:

```
public interface Page<T> extends Slice<T>
```

Comment: *" Is that not the same as..."* Correct, it is *not* the same.

Comment: Do you *need* to? No. It's just convenient not to repeat yourself by writing `Page<EmployeeEvent> employeeEventPage = new PageImpl<EmployeeEvent>(employeeEvents, null, 10);`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'd add why it's not the same: omitting the `<>` (with or without anything between them) means the expression is a [*raw type*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/3788176).

Comment: @AndyTurner - Well, it's covered by the dupetarget, so... :-)